# Optimizing MySQL query on large table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im using mysql with JDBC.

I have a large example table which contains 6.3 million rows that I am trying to perform efficient select queries on. See below:
[image]

I have created three additional indexes on the table, see below:
[image]

Performing a `SELECT` query like this `SELECT latitude, longitude FROM 3dag WHERE 
timestamp BETWEEN "+startTime+" AND "+endTime+" AND HourOfDay=4 AND DayOfWeek=3"` has a run time that is extremely high at 256356 ms, or a little above four minutes. My explain on the same query gives me this:
[image]

My code for retrieving the data is below:

```
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3306/testdb";
    String user = "bigd";
    String password = "XXXXX";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        String query = "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM 3dag WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "+startTime+" AND "+endTime+" AND HourOfDay=4 AND DayOfWeek=3";
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM 3dag WHERE timestamp>=" + startTime + " AND timestamp<=" + endTime);
        stmt = con.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        System.out.println("Start");
        while (rs.next()) {

            int tempLong = (int) ((Double.parseDouble(rs.getString(2))) * 100000);
            int x = (int) (maxLong * 100000) - tempLong;
            int tempLat = (int) ((Double.parseDouble(rs.getString(1))) * 100000);
            int y = (int) (maxLat * 100000) - tempLat;

            if (!(y > matrix.length) || !(y < 0) || !(x > matrix[0].length) || !(x < 0)) {
                matrix[y][x] += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End");
        JSONObject obj = convertToCRS(matrix);
        return obj;

    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        return null;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (pst != null) {
                pst.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Removing every line in the `while(rs.next())` loop gives me the same horrible run-time.

My question is what can I do to optimize this type of query? I am curious about the `.setFetchSize()` and what the optimal value should be here. Documentation shows that INTEGER.MIN_VALUE results in fetching row-by-row, is this correct?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
After creating a new index on timestamp, DayOfWeek and HourOfDay my query runs 1 minute faster and explain gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Please avoid screenshots and show your information in text form. It's much easier to read and to work with.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be the other way around. Is this an SO guideline, or just your personal preference?

Comment: One reason is that you can not copy&paste from an image :-)

Comment: What are maxLat, and maxLong, how are they set? They seem to determine if a value is actually **needed** in your matrix. If you found a way to put that into the WHERE condition, you'd need a lot less rows transported.

Comment: 63.42080 and 10.41207. I have performed data cleaning on the data set so that each lat long value is acceptable.

Comment: 1 second to execute `explain` seems to much for that simple query. Is it possible that your server is under high load?

Comment: @kongshem since the long explanation didnt catch your notice, off the top of my head i recommend that you redesign your table and remove hour of day and day of week, these can and should be calculated and not stored.

Comment: Sorry, Im testing everything you guys have proposed here to see what works and what does not, these queries takes a while, so it's not done in minutes. The only reason I created hour of day and day of week was because I thought it whould be faster to query with those parameters. Am I wrong here? The customer wants to have the possibility to select day of week, so the possibility of using that parameter is present.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas up front:

- Did you in fact check the SQL Execution time (from .executeQuery() till first row?) or is that execution + iteration over 6.3 million rows?
- You prepare a PreparedStatement but don't use it?!
- Use PreparedStatement, pass tiemstamp, dayOfWeek, hourOfDay as parameters
- Create **one** index that can satisfy your where condition. Order the keys in a way that you can eliminate the most items with the highest ranking field.

The idex might look like:

```
CREATE INDEX stackoverflow on 3dag(hourOfDay, dayOfWeek, Timestamp);
```

Perform your SQL inside MySQL - what time do you get there?

- Try without `stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);` this might create many unneeded network roundtrips.

Comment: Performing the query in the command line gives me the same run time. Creating an index as you suggested now, will report the results. As for the PreparedStatement, Im unable to set 'java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY', thats why I used Statement.

Comment: Well what number of lines do you expect to be returned? If it's not flooding your memory, you might be save with default options anyway.

Comment: One more thought - forcing MySQL to streaming might be slower than just pumping out the results into memory.

Comment: I was hoping that mysql would be faster than my mongoDB with the exact same data set. Mongo does the same query in about 1 minute. Creating the index as you proposed made the query 1 minute faster, so at least it's better :)

Comment: what does `explain` say now?

Comment: and see edit - try once without setFetchSize. Streaming results might cause many extra network roundtrips adding to your lag.

Comment: Removing the setFetchSize() did not improve the run time unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, the cardinality of (that is, the number of distinct values in) your `Timestamp` column is about 1/30th of the cardinality of your `Uid` column. That is, you have lots and lots of identical timestamps. That doesn't bode well for the efficiency of your query.

That being said, you might try to use the following [compound covering index](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727) to speed things up.

```
CREATE INDEX 3dag_q ON ('Timestamp' HourOfDay, DayOfWeek, Latitude, Longitude)
```

Why will this help? Because your whole query can be satisfied from the index with a so-called tight index scan. The MySQL query engine will random-access the index to the entry with the smallest Timestamp value matching your query. It will then read the index in order and pull out the latitude and longitude from the rows that match.

You could try doing some of the summarizing on the MySQL server.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) number_of_duplicates, 
       ROUND(Latitude,4) Latitude, ROUND(Longitude,4) Longitude
  FROM 3dag
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "+startTime+" 
                     AND "+endTime+"
   AND HourOfDay=4
   AND DayOfWeek=3
 GROUP BY ROUND(Latitude,4), ROUND(Longitude,4)
```

This may return a smaller result set.  **Edit** This quantizes (rounds off) your lat/long values and then count the number of items duplicated by rounding them off. The more coarsely you round them off (that is, the smaller the second number in the `ROUND(val,N)` function calls happens to be) more duplicate values you will encounter, and the fewer distinct rows will be generated by your query. Fewer rows save time.

Finally, if these lat/long values are GPS derived and recorded in degrees, it makes no sense to try to deal with more than about four or five decimal places. Commercial GPS precision is limited to that.

**More suggestions**

Make your latitude and longitude columns into `FLOAT` values in your table if they have GPS precision. If they have more precision than GPS use `DOUBLE`. Storing and transferring numbers in `varchar(30)` columns is quite inefficient.

Similarly, make your `HourOfDay` and `DayOfWeek` columns into `SMALLINT` or even `TINYINT` data types in your table. 64 bit integers for values between 0 and 31 is wasteful. With hundreds of rows, it doesn't matter. With millions it does.

Finally, if your queries always look like this

```
SELECT Latitude, Longitude
   FROM 3dag
  WHERE timestamp BETWEEN SOME_VALUE 
                      AND ANOTHER_VALUE
    AND HourOfDay = SOME_CONSTANT_DAY
    AND DayOfWeek = SOME_CONSTANT_HOUR
```

this compound covering index should be ideal to accelerate your query.

```
CREATE INDEX 3dag_hdtll ON (HourOfDay, DayofWeek, `timestamp`, Latitude, Longitude)
```

Comment: I think you read my matrix wrong, the size is 1371 x 838 :) I am using 5 decimals for each lat long value. Thanks anyway. I will look into summarizing suggestion.

Comment: Do try the covering index

Comment: Ok, so the result from the query you proposed gave me a run time of 2 minutes and 11 seconds. What exactly did this query do? Did it count the the resulting latitude and longitude values with four decimals? A quick run through of the output shows that a lot of the lat long values had 1 occurce, most of them had between 10 and 50 occurrences and the largest was about 400.

Comment: Changing the query to use 5 instead of 4 decimals generated a run time of 3 minutes.

Comment: Will perform your suggestions and get back to you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am extrapolating from my tracking app.  This is what i do for efficiency:

Firstly, a possible solution depends on whether or not you can predict/control the time intervals.  Store snapshots every X minutes or once a day, for example.  Let us say you want to display all events YESTERDAY.  You can save a snapshot that has already filtered your file.  This would speed things up enormously, but is not a viable solution for custom time intervals and real live coverage.

My application is LIVE, but usually works pretty well in T+5 minutes (5 minute maximum lag/delay).  Only when the user actually chooses live position viewing will the application open a full query on the live db.  Thus, depends on how your app works.

Second factor: How you store your timestamp is very important.  Avoid `VARCHAR`, for example.  If you are converting UNIXTIME that also will give you unnecessary lagtime. Since you are developing what appears to be a geotracking application, your timestamp would be in unixtime - an integer.  some devices work with milliseconds, i would recommend not using them.  `1449878400` instead of `1449878400000` (12/12/2015 0 GMT)

I save all my geopoint datetimes in unixtime seconds and use mysql timestamps only for timestamping the moment the point was received by server (which is irrelevant to this query you propose).

You might shave some time off accessing an indexed view instead of running a full a query.  Whether that time is significant in a large query is subject to testing.

Finally, you could shave an itsy bitsy more by not using `BETWEEN` and using something SIMILAR to what it will be translate into (pseudocode below)

```
WHERE (timecode > start_Time AND timecode < end_time)
```

See that i change `>=` and `<=` to `>` and `<` because chances are your timestamp will almost never be on the precise second and even if it is, you will rarely be afffected whether 1 geopoint/time event is or not displayed.

Comment: I am currently inserting the data into a new table with your proposed improvements of data types. I did it on a slightly larger set of the data with 32 million rows, so the insert takes a while. Will get back to you, thanks!

Comment: yeah, i saw that.  my bad.